# f3 program fails to detect sdCard but Windows can open it and play videos

Tags: usb-drive, sd-card, lubuntu

Bought two sd cards 128GB for video recording.  These are likely fake and one of them is clearly damaged.  I formatted one of them to FAT32 using GParted, inserted in security camera to record and no issues were apparent.  Except for the fact it only appears to utilize 3GB of the entire drive and then repeats, it seems like it's a fake and it loops.

I want evidence to get a refund, unfortunately for both sd cards that I mount, lsblk lists them as `mmcblk0`, however no MOUNTPOINT is provided for them and gparted finds them as `/dev/mmcblk0` but when I try to run f3write on them it complains that the path given is not a directory.

f3probe destructive simply reported back the sd card is damaged, but I'm not quite sure if it's actually carrying out the test or not, since f3write simply doesn't work.  How come Windows can read one of the drives and successfully report back to have formatted the other one but on Unix this doesn't appear to be possible?

```bsh
ben@ben-aspirev3571:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   457G  0 part /
└─sda2    8:2    0   8.8G  0 part 
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
mmcblk0 179:0    0 119.1G  0 disk
```

```bsh
ben@ben-aspirev3571:~$ sudo f3probe --destructive --time-ops /dev/mmcblk0
F3 probe 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Digirati Internet LTDA.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.

WARNING: Probing normally takes from a few seconds to 15 minutes, but
         it can take longer. Please be patient.

Bad news: The device `/dev/mmcblk0' is damaged

Device geometry:
                 *Usable* size: 0.00 Byte (0 blocks)
                Announced size: 119.08 GB (249737216 blocks)
                        Module: 128.00 GB (2^37 Bytes)
        Approximate cache size: 0.00 Byte (0 blocks), need-reset=no
           Physical block size: 512.00 Byte (2^9 Bytes)

Probe time: 10.19s
 Operation: total time / count = avg time
      Read: 19.8ms / 2049 = 9us
     Write: 10.17s / 2049 = 4.9ms
     Reset: 0us / 0 = 0us
```

```bsh
ben@ben-aspirev3571:~$ f3write /dev/mmcblk0
F3 write 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Digirati Internet LTDA.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.

f3write: Can't open path /dev/mmcblk0: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount them first, then give the mount point to f3write. f3write writes data files so it needs mounted media, it won’t write to a device file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).